# how to make 3 labels animate in a loop objective c

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I want to make 3 labels animate with user tap at view, but only last one label animate, why all labels in a column not animating, How can i make all of the 3 labels start animating with user gesture at view. any help...

` .

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{

    // Create UILabel for Column
    _lblA = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
    _lblA.tag = 100+i;
    _lblA.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _lblA.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    _lblA.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _lblA.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
    [self.gameLayer addSubview:_lblA];
    //lblA.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _lblA.text=[MainArrayFirst objectAtIndex:i];
    [_lblA sizeToFit];
    _lblA.hidden = YES;


    // add a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the label
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotTapped:)];
    [_lblA addGestureRecognizer:tap];
     }
 - (void) gotTapped:(id)sender {
  for (UILabel *v in _columnA) {
    v.hidden = !v.hidden;

}

  [self fadeIn];
     }



  -(void)fadeIn{

CABasicAnimation *fadein = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadein.delegate = self;
fadein.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
fadein.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
fadein.duration = 0.3;

[self.lblA.layer addAnimation:fadein forKey:@"fade"];
```

}

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first declare one array in .h file

```
NSMutableArray *arrLabel;
```

then add the all label in array

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {

        // Create UILabel for Column
        UILabel *_lblA = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
        _lblA.tag = 100+i;
        _lblA.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        _lblA.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        _lblA.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _lblA.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
        //lblA.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        _lblA.text=[MainArrayFirst objectAtIndex:i];
        [_lblA sizeToFit];
        _lblA.hidden = YES;

        [arrLabel addObject:_lblA];
        // add a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the label
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotTapped:)];
        [_lblA addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }
```

then finally change in animation function

```
-(void)fadeIn{

    for(int i=0;i<arrLabel.count;i++)
    {
        UILabel *tempLabel = (UILabel *)[arrLabel objectAtIndex:i];
        CABasicAnimation *fadein = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        fadein.delegate = self;
        fadein.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        fadein.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        fadein.duration = 0.3;

        [tempLabel.layer addAnimation:fadein forKey:@"fade"];
    }

}
```

Comment: i have one other question can you please help

Comment: ya sure ask please

Comment: i have 3 labels in a column with some text and its size is according to the text of some random number and i want an other column2 of of 3 empty labels when i tap on any label from column1  the size of empty labels will also be same as the size of texted  labels

Comment: so you mean to say you want to assign the column1 all label size to column2 all label size

Comment: yes, suppose you have 3 labels with text as label.text = a , label2.text = abc,label3.text = abcdef and all labels frame is  according to text as [label sizeTofit]  and if i tap on label of text a i should got column1 all labels size same as label of text a and so on for otheres

Comment: i mean if i tap on 10 pixel size label i should got all the column1 labels of size 10 pixel and if i tap on 40 pixel size label i should got column1 all labels of size 40 pixels

Comment: you can get the the lable width and height and use the for loop as we did above and set its height and width

Comment: i tried it but it making different size not as i want

Comment: can you try this CGRect rectLabel = self.lblA.frame;
    for(int i=0;i<arrLabel.count;i++)
    {
        UILabel *tempLabel = (UILabel *)[arrLabel objectAtIndex:i];
        tempLabel.frame = CGRectMake(tempLabel.frame.origin.x, tempLabel.frame.origin.y, rectLabel.size.width, rectLabel.size.height);
    }

Comment: yes it works but it give the size of last one label not all tapped labels

Comment: yes i put in a function and then call function in tap gesture method as here -(void)target{
    CGRect rectLabel = self.lblA.frame;
    for(int i=0;i<_columnC.count;i++) {
        UILabel *tempLabel = (UILabel *)[_columnC objectAtIndex:i];
        tempLabel.frame = CGRectMake(tempLabel.frame.origin.x, tempLabel.frame.origin.y, rectLabel.size.width, rectLabel.size.height);
    }
}

Comment: it giving the size of last label from columnA

Comment: ok let try this one -(void)gotTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    UILabel *tapLable = (UILabel *)[sender view];
    CGRect rectLabel = tapLable.frame;
    for(int i=0;i<arrLabel.count;i++)
    {
        UILabel *tempLabel = (UILabel *)[arrLabel objectAtIndex:i];
        tempLabel.frame = CGRectMake(tempLabel.frame.origin.x, tempLabel.frame.origin.y, rectLabel.size.width, rectLabel.size.height);
    }
}